# Do not can install Horsey plugin

Tags: html, plugins

The code for installing [Horsey plugin](https://github.com/bevacqua/horsey) is simple but it is not work. What I do wrong?

```
<header>
   <div class='parent'>
      <input id='ig'/>
      <pre>
         <code> 
            horsey(document.querySelector('input'), {
               source: [{ list: [
                  { value: 'banana', text: 'Bananas from Amazon Rainforest' },
                  { value: 'apple', text: 'Red apples from New Zealand' },
                  { value: 'orange', text: 'Oranges from Moscow' },
                  { value: 'lemon', text: 'Juicy lemons from the rich Amalfitan Coast' }
               ]}],
               getText: 'text',
               getValue: 'value'
            });
         </code>
      </pre>
   </div>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/horsey/4.0.1/horsey.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/horsey/4.0.1/horsey.min.css" media="all"> 
</header>
```

I see only standard input on page.

Answer (score 0):

You must write code like below:

```
<script src="https://www.malketiya.com/listgrid/horsey.min.js"></script>
<input id='ig'/>
<script>
horsey(document.getElementById('ig'), {
source: [{ list: [
    { value: 'banana', text: 'Bananas from Amazon Rainforest' },
    { value: 'apple', text: 'Red apples from New Zealand' },
    { value: 'orange', text: 'Oranges from Moscow' },
    { value: 'lemon', text: 'Juicy lemons from Amalfitan Coast' }
]}],
getText: 'text',
getValue: 'value'
});
</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.malketiya.com/listgrid/horsey.min.css" media="all">
```